# GUI with 3 Jbuttons, and a list that stores the selected buttons/list parameters and can display them separately

Tags: java

I want to make a GUI where I have a list where one item can be selected, 3 JButtons, ON, OFF and STATE. When the Jbutton "State" is selected a separate box pops up telling the user if they selected ON / OFF and which parameter they selected from the JList. This is my code so far. The pop up box keeps telling me that the heater is on, because it keeps reading on = true. Also, the part where I try to select off the list is completely wrong aswel for some reason I can't see.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class Heater extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Object state;
private boolean on;
private Object inten;

//private JList HeatIntensity;
private String intensity[] = {"Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5"};



public Heater() {

    super("Heater");

    //creating box
    box(intensity);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Heater();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String action = ae.getActionCommand();

    //if on button is pressed, on = true
    if (action.equals("ON")) {
        on = true;
    }

    //if off pressed on = false
    else if (action.equals("OFF")) {
        on = false;
    }
    if (action.equals("State")) {

        //if the on/off button was pressed then the state button, a new box pops up     telling if on / off
        if(on = true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "on");
        }
        else if(on = false)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Heawdadwqwdqwdater is off");

        }

    //when somthing is pressed on the list, show that in a new pop up box
    /*intensity.additemListener(
            new itemlistener(){
            public void itemChanged(ItemEvent event){
                if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ItemEvent.SELECTED);
                }
                } 
            } 
            );
            */
    }



    public void box(String[] a){

    //creating the box
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(new Dimension(900, 300));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //creating Jbuttons
    JButton buttonon = new JButton("ON");
    JButton buttonoff = new JButton("OFF");
    JButton buttonState = new JButton("State");
    //creating list

    JList list = new JList(a);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    add(list);

    //adding buttons
    add(buttonon);
    add(buttonoff);
    add(buttonState);
    buttonon.addActionListener(this);
    buttonoff.addActionListener(this);
    buttonState.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);   
}
}
```

Comment: so you cant see your buttons?

Comment: I can see them. It's just after I select them, my output is all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this chunk of code:

```
if(on = true){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "on");
}
else if(on = false)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Heawdadwqwdqwdater is off");
```

Doing `if (on = true)` assigns `true` to `on` instead of checking if it is `true`. That means that the code in the block will always be executed. The same applies for the `else if`, although it will never reach it.
The correct way to do this is

```
if (on) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "on");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Heawdadwqwdqwdater is off");
}
```